# Which Ruby server for an app with lots of file uploads?

Tags: web-server, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently building an application that will handle quite a lot of file uploads (images, so a few MB each). It'll also be handling mostly JSON requests on the frontend, behind a Javascript application.

Which Ruby server would be my best bet for maintaining good performance? Passenger, Unicorn, Rainbows, or Thin?

Comment: Instead of allowing your Ruby applications to handle the file uploads, take a look at the NGINX file upload module (http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html), let NGINX handle the uploads then your Ruby application just has to worry about moving the file to the right place

Answer (score 0):

You should always place an reverse proxy like Apache/nginx in front of Ruby application server. And use that reverse proxy as an load balancer to distribute request evenly to Ruby servers cluster.

If you only use the Ruby server as a service layer, replying json datas. You can use Thin, because you can build server in asynchronous pattern(reactor) which is more scalable.